# Simple sentence to understand lemma

Tags: graph-theory

Is there any other way to explain this sentence to make it easier to understand :

A hypergraph has property $H_t$ for some integer $t \geq 2$ if any $i$ edges intersect

Comment: The tag "intersection-theory" refers to [a particular subject in algebraic geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_theory), not the general study of intersections in (hyper)graphs, so I've removed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not a sentence to replace it, but some additional explanation?

A hypergraph is a natural extension of regular graphs in the sense that the concept of edges are generalized.

A normal graph is just a set of dots (vertices) with lines drawn between the dots (edges). An edge connects two dots together.

A hyperedge (turning the graph in to a hypergraph) just adds more vertices to the edges. Instead of an edge being a line connecting two vertices, it's now a blob with some number of vertices in the blob.

A manual test of property $P_t$ would be as such (for any fixed $t$):

For $i=2$, any grouping of 2 edges must have $t-1$ vertices in common.

For $i=3$, any grouping of 3 edges must have $t-2$ vertices in common.

For $i=4$, any grouping of 4 edges must have $t-3$ vertices in common.

Continue this up to $i=t$. If all of these work, then the graph has property $P_t$.

Answer (score 1):

I think the sentence you're asking about may be confusing because it makes it look like "property $P_t$" is something which has already been defined. In fact, that sentence is defining what property $P_t$ is. *(Note that $t$ here is a **parameter**, that is, we really have a property $P_2$, a property $P_3$, a property $P_4$, ... Also, note that we are explicitly told that $t$ is an integer greater than $2$ - we aren't going to define property $P_1$ or property $P_\pi$)*. That sentence tells us that when we say "$\mathcal{H}$ has property $P_t$," what we mean is: whenever we have $i$-many edges in $\mathcal{H}$ (for $i$ between $2$ and $t$) they intersect in at least $(t+1-i)$-many vertices. So, for example, $\mathcal{H}$ has property $P_3$ iff:

- Any $2$ edges in $\mathcal{H}$ intersect in at least $2$ points. ($t=3, i=2$)
- Any $3$ edges in $\mathcal{H}$ intersect in at least $1$ point. ($t=3, i=3$).

Lemma $3$ then connects this sort of property with the existence of certain colorings of the hypergraph in question.